# XSLT engine removing whitespace from <xsl:text> element in text output

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a transformation that outputs a fixed length output, so where data is "missing" I pad the data with spaces.
so using

```
   <xsl:output method="text" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
```

and then using things like

```
        <xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
```

whenever I need to pad for missing data.

This works very nicely in my dev environment (using visual studio).

but when I deploy it to another machine (which also uses MS XSLT engine, but with unknown parameters, allegedly 6.0), some of my whitespace gets "removed" and my data gets misalligned.

If I replace the above with things like

```
        <xsl:text>&#x20;&#x20;</xsl:text>
```

then that doesnt get stripped.
this also works

```
<xsl:text xml:space="preserve">  </xsl:text>
```

Is there a way to get the XSLT to 'preserve' standard spaces in the "text" elements globally?

(the transformation is quite big and I don't want to have to go through replacing every space with   , plus it worries me that its not doing 'exactly' what I'm asking it to do)

(I've looked at other questions on this, which is where I got the   from, but I'd like to turn the XSLT behaviour OFF)

Comment: Is it possible that on your other machine some extra steps are being done?

Comment: Please provide a way to reproduce the problem - see: [mcve].

Comment: Check how the stylesheet XML is being parsed. Microsoft parsers have a habit of stripping whitespace unless you ask them nicely not to.

Comment: I think this is the issue, I think there is a setting on the engine, and I have no control over it, so I'm stuck with the "preserve" solution.